# Submitting a Watchkit App to the Appstore - do I create a new App or is it somehow part of my iPhone App

Tags: watchkit

I tried to load my App to iTunesConnect today but I got an error during the build re. no provisioning profile found (when I run it just for my iPhone App it works just fine and has been fine for a while now).  So I assume this is because I have added a Watchkit App.

How do I resolve this ?

Do I need to create a new App in iTunesConnect for the Watchkit app ?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way I read through this and am still not clearer : https://developer.apple.com/app-store/watch/

Comment: Just to add a note, even though watchOS 2 provides somewhat native apps, they are still installed and managed from iOS, so they still depend on an iOS side of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* need to create a new app for your watch app. It's a *part* of your main app as an *extension*.

You could resolve your problem by *just signing out* from the account settings in Xcode and then *signing in again*. Worked for me.

1. First of all click onto the accounts tab.

[image: Click on the "Accounts" tab]

2. Then select your Apple-ID and click minus.

[image: Then select your Apple-ID and click minus.]

3. Then click onto the plus button and add your Apple-ID once again.